# Discord.js kick/ban permisions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm working on a Discord bot and making the kick/ban command but I have a problem with the permissions:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'ban',
  description: "This command bans a member!",
  execute(message, args) {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(target) {
      const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
      memberTarget.ban();
      message.channel.send("User has been banned");
    }
    else {
      message.channel.send(`You coudn't ban that member!`);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand what you mean, but I assume you want the command to work for certain members with the kick/ban permissions.

You could use `.hasPermission()`, and an example of using it is the code below.

```
if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) { // "KICK_MEMBERS" for kicking
      //your code
} else {
      message.reply('You do not have the permissions!')
}
```

If this does not answer your question then I am sorry.

Comment: Thanks man im new in coding and i dont know mach thanks